# Video formats/length?

Tags: video, mp4

Could the same file in different video formats have the different length?
For example if I decode the movie in mp4 to some exotic video format - could this reduce or extend the length of the movie?

Comment: yes, it will, because it will adjust according to its own format and then play with pixel, to convert in given format

Comment: You mean "length" in time? In theory, probably, if you change the frame rate. As it stands this is rather vague, what is the real-world issue you are facing?